# JNI Camera Signature

Tags: java-native-interface, signature

I recently meet a request of JNI in my project , I don't know how to signature my native method, It's like  `public void  f(byte[] byte, Camera camera)`

I know `byte[]`'s signature is `([B)V`, but the camera really troubles me, can anyone please help me with this signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature depends on what you are doing on the native side.

If you were doing your camera readinf in C, well it would look like this.

The signature on the Java side looks like

```
class TestMe {
public native void acquireFromCamera(int camera, byte[] buffer);
}
```

Javah makes a header file like

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class TestMe */

#ifndef _Included_TestMe
#define _Included_TestMe
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     TestMe
 * Method:    acquireFromCamera
 * Signature: (I[B)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestMe_acquireFromCamera
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jbyteArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endifm
#endif
```

If you pass a buffer array from Java down to JNI don't forget to lock the buffer before passing it. Otherwise the GC might move it while you are acquiring.

The C side call parameters are

```
(JNIEnv *myEnvironment, jobject this, jint camera, jbyteArray buffer);
```

this sort of interface works well if the underlying C function(s) you wanted to use  looks vaguely like this...

void readCamera(int camera, unsigned char * data);

If the underlying C library requires you to open the camera/acquisition stream first that is best done in one JNI function and reading in another.
Your native code ends up in a single DLL/Shared library will only be loaded once.

It's not hard to get camera interfacing working form Java to C code.

Your C code can call methods on Java code. Do it in your JNI method and it is pretty painless.

I would not recommend trying to do asynchronous callbacks from your library to Java.  It can be done but is very time consuming and hard to get to not leak memory.

Comment: i tried javah with object Camera camera , it ended up with "Landroid/Hardware/Camera;" , finally... :)